# Make a simple format (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

### The goal

Convert `99999999` into `99999-999`.

### The problem

I do not know the syntax.

### What I already thought about

I was thinking to use`FORMAT()` function — but I'm working with *INT* instead of *DECIMAL*.

### My query

```
Select city.ZipCode As zipCode
From app_cities As city
Where city.Id = 1
```

So, that's it. Someone has any idea to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're going to have with zip codes is that there can be a leading 0.  So the length of the zip code can either be 7 or 8 digits.

So, the zipcode might be 02323-213 or 12133-333.  As an int, you will lose the first digit.

Taking what Jurgen D already posted and modifying it.

```
SELECT insert(LPAD(zipcode, 8, '0'), 6, 0, '-') from zipcodes;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2e255/1)

Comment: I marked this answer as accepted because I'll use this solution — it is more complete than @JuergenD's answer. By the way, thank you two! Amazing answers!

Answer (score 4):

Use [INSERT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_insert)

```
select insert(ZipCode , 6, 0, '-') As zipCode
from app_cities As city
where Id = 1
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/16786)

Comment: As I said to @BrianHoover, I marked his answer as accepted because I'll use his solution — it is a little more complete than yours —, but your entry solved my problem too. Thanks, fella!

Answer (score 0):

```
select concat(substring(cast(999999999 as char),5),'-',
              (substring(cast(999999999 as char),6,4)));
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/16794)

from table:

```
select concat(substring(cast(ZipCode as char),5),'-',
              (substring(cast(ZipCode as char),6,4)));
```